# Converting decimal to hexadecimal

Tags: c#, hex, decimal

I have an input that is in non-US ASCII range decimal values that I'm having issues converting to Hexadecimal value.

How would I convert a decimal value of for example 552 to its hexadecimal value of 228?

Comment: What type is this "non-US ASCII range decimal" variable?

Comment: @CodeCaster Higher decimal values that belong to characters that are not the standard printing characters in US https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Comment: I know what ASCII is, I don't know what it has to do with converting a number's base.

Comment: I was getting results I wanted in lower ranges but not in higher ones

Comment: In that case you should [edit] your question to show your code, explain what problem you have with it and show what you have tried to fix it. Anyway, see duplicate.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `Convert.ToString(552, 16)`.

[Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14kwkz77)